# Remove the group of rows based on the condition of rows

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe which has two columns, 'Group' and 'Sample Number'
The column 'Group' has sample number '11' which is UNIQUE. and each group will have only one '11' Sample Number, followed by the sample numbers in range of 21 to 29 ( for example, 21, 22 23, 24, 25, 26, 27 , 28 , 29) and followed by the sample numbers in range of 31 to 39 (for example, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39). **Hence each group should have one '11' sample number, at least one sample number in the range of 21 to 29 and at least one sample number in the rande of 31 to 39.**

I wish to compute in such a way that my code goes through each group and

1. Check if there is a sample number 11 in the group or not.
2. Check if there is at least one sample number in the range of 21
   to 29 .
3. Check if there is at least one sample number in the range
   of 31 to 39

**If any of these three conditions does not match then the code removes the entire group from the dataframe**

Below is the dataframe in table format:

| Group | Sample_Number |
| --- | --- |
| Z007 | 11 |
| Z007 | 21 |
| Z007 | 22 |
| Z007 | 23 |
| Z007 | 31 |
| Z007 | 32 |
| Z008 | 11 |
| Z008 | 31 |
| Z008 | 32 |
| Z008 | 33 |
| Z009 | 11 |
| Z009 | 21 |
| Z009 | 22 |
| Z009 | 23 |
| Z010 | 21 |
| Z010 | 22 |
| Z010 | 23 |
| Z010 | 24 |
| Z010 | 31 |
| Z010 | 32 |
| Z010 | 33 |
| Z010 | 34 |

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[Z007, 11],[Z007, 21] , [Z007, 22], [Z007, 23], [Z007, 31],[Z007, 32],[Z008, 11],[Z008, 31],[Z008, 32],[Z008, 33],[Z009, 11],[Z009, 21],[Z009, 22],[Z009, 23], [Z010, 21],[Z010, 22],[Z010, 23], [Z010, 24],[Z010, 31],[Z010, 32],[Z010, 33],[Z010, 34], columns=['Group', 'Sample_Number'])
```

The code should remove the group 'Z008' as it does not have the sample number in the range of 21 to 29. It should remove the group 'Z009' as it does not have the sample number in the range of 31 to 39. Also it should remove the group 'Z010' as it does not have the sample number '11'.

Expected answer is below:

| Group | Sample_Number |
| --- | --- |
| Z007 | 11 |
| Z007 | 21 |
| Z007 | 22 |
| Z007 | 23 |
| Z007 | 31 |
| Z007 | 32 |

I could do it only for sample number 11 but struggling to do the same for the other sample numbers in the range of (21 to 29 ) and (31 to 39), below is the code for sample number 11

```
invalid_group_no = [i for i in df['Group'].unique() if
               df[df['Group']== i]["Sample_Number"].to_list().count(11)!=1]
```

Can anyone please help me with the other sample numbers? Please feel free to implement your own ways. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, can you post your dataframe following these informations ? [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @ErnestBidouille give me few mins, I will do so.

Comment: @ErnestBidouille , I have added the dataframe in the format you had asked for. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
groups = set(df['Group'][df['Sample_Number'] == 11]) & set(df['Group'][df['Sample_Number'].isin(range(21,30))]) & set(df['Group'][df['Sample_Number'].isin(range(31,40))])
df = df[df['Group'].isin(groups)]
```

```
   Group    Sample_Number
0   Z007               11
1   Z007               21
2   Z007               22
3   Z007               23
4   Z007               31
5   Z007               32
```